# Store and display scraped content from xml file

Tags: php, jquery, xml

As of my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17858079/scrape-div-contents-using-php-and-curl/17858692#17858692), I scraped the content and displayed in a html page using the code below:

```
<?php
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$target_url="http://www.amazon.in/gp/bestsellers/books/1318209031/ref=zg_bs_nav_b_2_1318203031";
$html = new simple_html_dom();
$html->load_file($target_url);
?>

<html>
<body>
<div style="margin:auto;width:900px">
<?php
foreach($html->find('div[class=zg_itemWrapper]') as $post)
{
    echo $post;
}
?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to store the same in an Xml file and display 10 items each time I scroll down the page using jQuery's `window.scroll()` function.
My question is how do I store this scraped data in Xml file for displaying? (instead of using a database or similar ways to store)
I couldn't find any proper solution for doing the same.
I'm new to using xml this way. An implementation would really help,
thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to create page that will send only post with `page` parameter that will print `n` page. and then you can use [infinite ajax scrol](http://www.fieg.nl/infinite-ajax-scroll-a-jquery-plugin) jquery plugin.

**UPDATE**: Here is [the code how to use the plugin](http://www.jqueryscript.net/other/jQuery-Infinite-Ajax-Scroll-Plugin-ias-js.html), using this just create a php script that will have just the foreach loop with post just for `n` page.

Comment: i'm relatively new to using xml this way. An implementation would really help
tq

Comment: thank you for sharing a very useful info about the jQuery plugin.
I really need help with the xml thing. Can you help with displaying the html content in xml file.

Comment: @John maybe you should ask another question: "How split xml file into pages" or something like that.

Comment: that was my actual question. Your suggestion about jQuery was helpful, what I really want is a way to store this dynamic scraped content in an Xml file(and if possible, display dynamic content from it, the same way one can do using a database).

Comment: as I told, your suggestion about the plugin was very useful. It gave me an idea that I should also have knowledge on ajax to fulfill what I'm implementing. Altogether, it was informative. So..

Comment: @John I don't know how to split xml into pages, and when you accept my answer you'll proably don't get another one. You should unaccept the answer and wait for another one, or ask another question. "How to split xml file into pages" is good title.

Comment: Ok. sorry for the confusion.